# NSDocument could not be opened in app with multiple document types

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument, uti

My app has two custom document types. Both are declared, and their UTIs exported, in the target. Both UTIs conform to public.data and public.content; and the documents both use NSKeyedArchiver for reading and writing to disk.

Within the NSDocument subclass for DocumentType1, I'm using the following code to open a document of DocumentType2 after having run an NSOpenPanel to find out which URL to open:

```
self.docType2FileURL = [openPanel URLs][0];
NSLog(@"docType2FileURL: %@", self. docType2FileURL);
NSError *err = nil;
self.docType2FileSecurityScopedBookmark = [NSURL bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:self.docType2FileURL error:&err];
if (err != nil) {
    NSLog(@"bookmark error: %@", err);
}
NSLog(@"bookmark: %@", self.docType2FileSecurityScopedBookmark);
[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:self.docType2FileURL display:NO completionHandler:^(NSDocument *document, BOOL documentWasAlreadyOpen, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No error.");
    }
    self.docType2pointer = (DocumentType2 *)document;
}];
```

This is failing, and resulting in the following log statements:

> 2012-10-07 11:05:37.956 MyApp[64151:303] docType2FileURL: file://localhost/path/to/file2.docType2
>
> 2012-10-07 11:05:37.958 MyApp[64151:303] bookmark error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file couldn’t be opened."
>
> 2012-10-07 11:05:37.959 MyApp[64151:303] bookmark: (null)
>
> 2012-10-07 11:05:38.015 MyApp[64151:303] Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The document “name of file.docType2” could not be opened. MyApp cannot open files of this type." UserInfo=0x1001b2c30 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=MyApp cannot open files of this type., NSLocalizedDescription=The document “name of file.docType2” could not be opened. MyApp cannot open files of this type., NSUnderlyingError=0x1005db460 "“name of file.docType2” could not be handled because MyApp cannot open files of this type."}

For whatever reason, not only is the document not opening, but the app is also unable to create a bookmark to it. Do you have any ideas on why that could be?

Thanks in advance.